# Display My Account navigation on all pages of Customer

Tags: magento

I want to display My Account navigation on all pages of customer i.e when customer edit his account or view his orders etc. but presently i am getting the navigation only on Customer account page.How can i do this in magento.

Comment: you need to show the customer navigation in order view page and list page?

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follows :

locate `customer.xml` in your theme i.e `app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/YOURTHEME/layout/customer.xml`

find`<customer_account translate="label">` with label `<label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>` in this file.

you can view `<reference name="left">` below these search.

Add whatever links you need to display in the block

```
<block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
```

Please message for futher queries.

Regards